# My javascript popup shows for a split second if there's a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. It works it just shows the popup for a split second. Would a timeout option be better? Which part is the problem? I'm a little new to Javascript so I don't really know what to exactly look for.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
/** Create a html cookie and set expiry as a day. **/
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   var expires = date.toGMTString();
   document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expires+"; path=/";
}
/** Check if already a cookie has been created. **/
function readCookie(name) {
    var flag = 0;
    var dcmntCookie = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < dcmntCookie.length;i++) {
        var ck = dcmntCookie[i];
        while (ck.charAt(0)==' ') {
            ck = ck.substring(1,ck.length);
        }
        if(ck) {
            cparts = ck.split('=');
            if (cparts[0] == name) flag=1;
        }              
    }     
    if(flag) { 
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false; 
    }  
}
/** Check if cookie exists else create a new one. **/
function checkCookie(name) {
    if (readCookie(name)) {
        document.getElementById('google').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('google').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    else createCookie(name,"cookie 4 the day",1); 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function closeThisDiv()

{

var openDiv = document.getElementById('google');

openDiv.style.display = 'none';

}
</script>
<body onLoad="checkCookie('MyCookie')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have the element with `id="google"` to be hidden from the very beginning of the page display (so it never shows), then you should add a CSS rule that loads in the head section like this:

```
#google {display: none;}
```

Or, you should add a style element to the HTML itself:

```
<div id="google" style="display:none"></div>
```

---

As your code is currently written, it sounds like it is doing what it is supposed to.  It waits for the entire document to be loaded (including images) and then it hides the element with `id="google"`.  That means the item will show briefly while the page is loading and then your code will hide it.

If you can't modify the CSS or the HTML for the google object and you're just trying to hide it as soon as possible with javascript and the google object is present in the HTML of your page (not added programmatically), then you can do this:

```
<body>
other HTML here

<script>
// script that executes right before the /body tag
checkCookie("MyCookie")
</script>

</body>
```

This will at least not wait for all images to load before hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this:

Create a css property of display:none; for #google

```
#google{display:none;}
```

Then switch around the last portion of code to display only if they don't have the cookie, and to create the cookie.

```
/** Check if cookie exists else create a new one. **/
function checkCookie(name) {
    if (readCookie(name)) {

    }
    else document.getElementById('google').style.display = "inline";
         document.getElementById('google').style.visibility = "visibility";
         createCookie(name,"cookie 4 the day",1);
```

In case anyone runs into this problem. Worked great for me.